# Label refuses to disappear with [label setHidden:YES]; command in a if-method?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to customize my tableView in my IOS app. When my tableView(or rather array) is empty, I want to display a customized label instead of the items in the tableView. The label I am referring to is "label0". But something is terribly wrong, my [label0 setHidden:YES]; or [label0 setHidden:NO]; only works in the first block of the if "method"? In the second block (if else) nothing happens no matter what I try to set the label as (hidden or shown).

What have I missed? I cannot see my own fault?

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,     tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
UILabel *label0 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25,  tableView.bounds.size.width - 0, 100)] autorelease];

if ([self.searchResults count] == 0){

headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lista2.png"]];

UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 5, 18)] autorelease];
label.text = @"Information";
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[headerView addSubview:label];

 label0.text = @"Test test test";
  label0.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 label0.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 [tableView addSubview:label0];
  [label0 setHidden:NO];

 }

 else {

headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lista2.png"]];

UILabel *label2 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 5, 18)] autorelease];
label2.text = @"Search results";
label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[headerView addSubview:label2];
[label0 setHidden:YES];       

}

 return headerView;
}
```

**EDIT**

I have moved the code to viewDidLoad and set the property for the UILabel. This have unfortunately not solved my problem....

```
UILabel *label0 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25,    tableView.bounds.size.width - 0, 100)] autorelease];
[tableView addSubview:label0];

   if ([self.searchResults count] == 0){

       label0.text = @"Test test test";
       label0.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       label0.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [label0 setHidden:NO];
   }
   else {
      [label0 setHidden:YES];
   }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through this with the debugger?  Perhaps the issue is your count is always 0, even when you think it should be something else when you are testing.  If searchResults is getting setup wrong, you might think you are putting values in it when you actually aren't.  Thus, the count would always be 0, and you would always run the first block's code (and never see the else, and therefore never execute setHidden:YES).

Comment: No, the count is working as it should. It can easily be seen as the tableView add's its objects under the label0 when it is supposed to be hidden. I have now spent 3 hours to this problem and still have not found the problem :S

Answer (score 0):

This is because your label0 is created every time this method is called so in "else" you are referring to totally different object (not the one that you added to tableView when array was empty).

You shouldn't be adding subviews to tableView from this method. Consider using viewDidLoad. That way you will be adding label0 only once. To achieve that add label0 as property of your viewController.

Comment: Already tried that, the result is exactly the same. It only listens to the first block in the if-method...?

Comment: 1. Add property to your viewController, 2. do not create label0 every time you call viewForHeader, 3. add label0 to tableView only once in viewDidLoad and never in viewForHeader, what exactly did you try?

Comment: @JesperMartensson i beg to differ. Tomasz is correct. Every time your code is executed it will refer to a different label. To add to that `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is completely the wrong method for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Done everything you say here, the result is still the same, it only listens to the first block in the if-statement... I now have the code in viewDidLoad and also have set the property for the UILabel..... :(

Comment: @JesperMartensson viewDidLoad is only executed once, hiding and unhiding should be done elsewhere. Normally it should be model that sends notification to your viewController that something changed then you can change visibility of your UILabel. I see you have search Results in viewController so you should change hidden state in the place where you change searchResults(just after changing it).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `label0` as subview please put this line in the else statement

```
 [tableView addSubview:label0];
```

also I cannot see any benefit from doing so. I believe you can just hide the table view and show another view that has the label. but nesting views that way is not good when you come back to debug this code after 1 month you will struggle to understand it.

Comment: Seems it is added within Jesper's code - check his code; about 6 lines above that `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You say in your edit that you set the property for the UILabel (I assume you mean that you have a property called label0?). If this is so, then when you alloc init your label, it should be self.label0 = .....  not UILabel *label0 = .....